# How to implement React-bootstrap in css modules?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, css-modules

Recently i moved to css modules but i am also using react-bootstrap in my existing project and i am not able to figure out how to include react-bootstrap in css modules,any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bootstrap module.

Run below command to install.

`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

And then simply import CSS in your index.js or App.js.

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`